# Windows 8 unique "desktop" to make an "app" out of a program

Tags: windows-8, multiple-desktop, windows-8-apps

Sorry I didn't know how to ask this question without labelling it "Windows 8 multiple desktops" Which brings up a whole bunch of people trying to do something else.

I like the "swype" alt-tab alternative in windows 8, but that only tabs between "apps", not programs running within the "desktop" app.

Google Chrome lets you run it either in desktop mode or "windows 8 mode" So that's nice, but what about all the other programs in the world? (Many of which support a very nice full-screen mode).

What I want is either a way to:

- Force any full-screen windows program to act like a windows 8 "app", or
- Instantiate multiple "desktop" apps, in which I can full-screen various programs. Ideally even rename them from "desktop" to whatever that app is.

Hopefully this can be done!

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this a bad question?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done.

The classical desktop and the modern apps are two separate worlds.

- Classical desktop applications are those that (can) run on previous versions of Windows.
- Modern apps are the new thing in Windows 8, they didn't exist before. These applications have new API to the system and are run in a more restrictive environment than regular (or classic) desktop applications.
  <sub>The only exception is made to browsers which can use the full Windows API even in modern interface, and can be run as either desktop or modern mode.</sub>

You cannot start multiple desktop "apps" because it's not really an application, it's just the "legacy" Windows desktop presented as a tile.

Comment: multiple virtual desktop tools like dexpot let you create multiple "desktops" on windows, all it would take is for one of those tools to build a win8 savvy version. I assume it's been done or in the works...

Comment: Yes, but that would still be a virtual desktop which runs on one Windows desktop. You would not be able to switch between such desktops the same way you switch between modern apps.